# Make HTML element be handled as background in print

Tags: html, css, printing

If I print a Website, the dialog has the option to print (or not print) the background.

I'm currently working on a page that is printed with different computers on different printers. One of the printers has custom paper with the company logo and some legal stuff in the footer. The other printers use blank paper.

So I implemented the logo as a background image and deactivated "print backgrounds" on the computer with the fancy paper and activated it on the rest.
This works fine with the logo, but I can't find a way to do the same for the footer.

An online search (with several different prompts) gave a lot of stuff about background images, but nothing about html/text.

Is there a way to mark an html element (containing text) as background, so it is removed in print if "print backgrounds" is not selected? Or do I have to <del>make a screenshot and</del> implement it as a picture?

[Edit]
SVG is a possibility, but suboptimal. It can easily be generated dynamically so I can implement a centralised control for stuff like adress data. But the text in it doesn't respond to the default css, forcing me to have different places/methods of styling for different parts of the same document. I would like to avoid that if possible (clean code and all that...).

Answer (score 1):

To keep the quality of the footer's text compose the logo and the footer as a single **SVG** file.

There is no technical problem, having the logo as a bitmap and keeping the the footer's text as vector graphics or "text with font assignment" (when using a common font).

This you can use as background image preserving your current solution.

A possible and free tool to manage this would be 'inkscape' (save as "plain SVG").

If you are able to manually code SVGs there would be even more possibilites to get the file optimized.

Comment: SVG is definitively better than just creating  screenshot. Thanks for the idea. But I want the text in the footer to respond to css if possible. So this would still be a last resort if I can't make normal html code be considered background...

Comment: SVGs are writable code and do use CSS style elements. They are not another cryptic binary. — The other way to get your final job done would be using Javascript. But I don't know if a web document will have access to informations about your local printer. This could pass the point, where you have to use a browser plugin to evaluate the printer name and decide whether to switch off the Corporate Identity layout or not. — ***Decide:** Add the tag **SVG** or **JavaScript** to your request, depending which way you want to go. – So the right people will get your request listed.*